# Running .net Application on localhost developed in VS 2017 gets an error "The requested operation requires elevation"

Tags: .net

I get elevation error when i tried running an .net application on localhost.
Note: I am running the VS(2017) in admin mode also I have cleaned up the Temp files, broswer cache. still i get the same error. i have tried changing the permission to the folder which contains my project (aspx pages etc). still no luck. PLz help 
Find the trace below.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
The requested operation requires elevation
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested 
operation requires elevation
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The requested operation requires elevation]

[ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being 
executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" 
 /noconfig /fullpaths 
@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET 
  Files\root\088ff0ab\c996293c\r4kmtosv.cmdline".]
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserToken
Handle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, 
 String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine) +2668
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle 
userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, 
  String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine) +117
 Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, 
String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& 
           outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs) +258
     Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters 
     options, String[] fileNames) +643
    Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +186
  System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +23
System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +913
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +296
System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +246
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +29
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +298
  [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\088ff0ab\c996293c\r4kmtosv.cmdline".]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +63
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +408
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +16
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, 
 PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +665

 [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\088ff0ab\c996293c\r4kmtosv.cmdline".]
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +673
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +453
________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
Version:4.6.1055.0
```

Comment: Try running your application in admin mode

Comment: Am running in admin mode. even i have seen in many post people say run in admin mode. it may works for few. but doesnt work in my case. i dont understand y am i getting this error. earlier i was able to launch the application. afetr many modification i end up with this error.